# can we set FFMPEG hardware acceleration if driver available otherwise use default?

Tags: ffmpeg, hardware-acceleration

I need to set ffmpeg code in such a way that if hardware acceleration is available it should be use it otherwise go with the available default driver. I am working with a screen recording software which is programmed in visual c++. So I need to implement hardware acceleration if it installed computer have GPU,
otherwise go with the CPU.

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -f gdigrab -framerate 24 -probesize 42M -i desktop  -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p camera1.mp4
```

I tried the above code but it is not working because my computer doesn't have CUDA or GPU support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## List available hardware acceleration methods

See the `-hwaccels` option:

> `-hwaccels`
> List all hardware acceleration methods supported in this build of ffmpeg.

Example:

```
$ ffmpeg -v error -hwaccels
  Hardware acceleration methods:
  vdpau
  cuda
  vaapi
  qsv
  drm
```

## Or use auto

To automatically select the hardware acceleration method:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel auto -i input ... output
```